# Remove File extension from the name by using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the way to remove file extensions from the name by using BigQuery?

```
E.g. --- XXX.jpg to XXX and e.t.c
```

I found a lot of solutions in SQL Server, but nothing for BigQUery

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([field]),0,CHARINDEX('[expr]',REVERSE([field]))))
```

Comment: Just a hint: BigQuery has native [Regex support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains)

Comment: REVERSE is also present in BQ string functions and STRPOS can be used instead of CHARINDEX, SUBSTR for  SUBSTRING. See [String functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substr)

Comment: `REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(name),0,STRPOS('.',REVERSE(name))))` Have empty result

Comment: Well, STRPOS is defined as STRPOS(string, substring). So STRPOS(REVERSE(name), '.'). Also SUBSTR is a bit different, but nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example is just one of the many options for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'xxx.jpg' name_with_extension UNION ALL
  SELECT 'yyy.png' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaa.bbb.xyz'
)
SELECT name_with_extension, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(name_with_extension, r'(.*)\..*$') name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row name_with_extension name     
1   xxx.jpg             xxx  
2   yyy.png             yyy  
3   aaa.bbb.xyz         aaa.bbb
```

Or using string manipulation functions:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name_with_extension, 
  SUBSTR(name_with_extension, 1, LENGTH(name_with_extension) - STRPOS(REVERSE(name_with_extension), '.')) name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

obviously with the same output